# Expanding [optionals], groupings, and the | or operator in text

Tags: regex, perl, enumeration, state-machine

I am trying to expand sentences that incorporate `[ ]` to indicate optionals, `( )` to indicate grouping, and `|` to indicate the `or` operator and enumerate all possibilities. So for example:

`"Hey [there] you [hood]."` should return four sentences:

```
Hey there you hood.
Hey there you.
Hey you hood.
Hey you.
```

The end goal would look like:

`Input: "(His|Her) dog was [very|extremely] confused."`

```
Output: His dog was very confused.
        His dog was extremely confused.
        His dog was confused.
        Her dog was very confused.
        Her dog was extremely confused.
        Her dog was confused.
```

I am doing it using regex matching and recursion. I have searched both CPAN and SO under the phrases:

Expanding text
expanding sentences
expanding conditionals
expanding optionals
expanding groupings

with no luck.

Thanks.

---

I have edited this question largely to better reflect its evolution and removed large portions which were made obsolete as the question evolved. The question above is the question that most of the answers below are attempting to address.

My current state is the following:

After wrestling with the problem above for a day I have two solutions very close to what I want. One is my own and the second is PLT's below. However, I have decided to try a fundamentally different approach.

Using regular expressions and manually parsing these sentences seems like a very ugly way of doing things. So I have decided to instead write a grammar for my "language" and use a parser-generator to parse it for me.

This gives me an additional layer of abstraction and avoids the following scenario described by Damian Conway in Perl Best Practices: [about regexps]

> cut-and-paste-and-modify-slightly-and-oh-now-it-doesn't-work-at-all-so-let's-modify-it-some-more-and-see-if-that-helps-no-it-didn't-but-we're-commited-now-so-maybe-if-we-change-that-bit-instead-hmmmm-that's-closer-but-still-not-quite-right-maybe-if-I-made-that-third-repetition-non-greedy-instead-oops-now-it's-back-to-not-matching-at-all-perhaps-I-should-just-post-it-to-PerlMonks.org-and-see-if-they-know-what's-wrong

It also makes it much easier if the grammar of these expressions were to change and I needed to support other constructs later on.

---

Last update:

I solved my problem using an [open source toolkit](http://people.csail.mit.edu/ilh/fst/). This will transcribe a JSGF version of my input and generate a finite-state transducer. From there you can walk through the FST to generate all possible outcomes.

Comment: `[there]` does not mean "there" or not "there". It means one letter in {t,h,e,r}.

Comment: @Aif: That is when you use [ ] in regular expressions. My input data contains [ ] which are literal and should not be confused with the regular expression [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, *another* complete revision of the answer. This **will** work as intended. :) It now also expands nested parens. Newline is still the delimeter, but I added a way to quickly change it to something more complicated if the need arises.

Basically, I started with replacing brackets with parens + pipe, since `[word ]` and `(|word )` are equivalent.

I then extracted all the encapsulating parens, e.g. both `(you |my friend)` and `(you |my (|friendly ) friend )`. I then expanded the nested parens into regular parens, e.g. `(you |my (|friendly ) friend )` was replaced with `(you |my friendly friend |my friend )`.

With that done, the words could be processed with the original subroutine.

Remains to be tested on more complicated expansions, but it works fine during my testing.

Here's the revised code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub addwords {
    my ($aref, @words) = @_;
    my @total;
    for my $start (@$aref) {
        for my $add (@words) {
            push @total, $start . $add;
        }
    }
    return @total;
}

sub expand_words {
    my $str = shift;
    my @sentences = ('');
    for my $word (word_split($str)) {
        if ($word =~ /^([(])([^)]+)[)]$/) {
            my @options = split /\|/, $2;
            push @options, '' if ($1 eq '[');
            @sentences = addwords(\@sentences, @options);
        } else {
            @sentences = addwords(\@sentences, $word);
        }
    }
    return @sentences;
}

sub fix_parens {
    my $str = shift;
    $str =~ s/\[/(|/g;
    $str =~ s/\]/)/g;
    return $str;
}

sub fix_nested {
    my @array = @_;
    my @return;
    for (my $i=0; $i <= $#array; ) {
        my $inc = 1;
        my ($co, $cc);
        do {
            $co = () = $array[$i] =~ /\(/g;
            $cc = () = $array[$i] =~ /\)/g;
            if ( $co > $cc ) {
                $array[$i] .= $array[$i + $inc++];
            }
        } while ( $co > $cc );
        push @return, expand_nest($array[$i]);
        $i += $inc;
    }
    return @return;
}

sub expand_nest {
    my $str = shift;
    my $co = () = $str =~ /\(/g;
    return $str unless ($co > 1);
    while ($str =~ /([^|(]+\([^)]+\)[^|)]+)/) {
        my $match = $1;
        my @match = expand_words($match);
        my $line = join '|', @match;
        $match =~ s/([()|])/"\\" . $1/ge;
        $str =~ s/$match/$line/ or die $!;
    }
    return $str;
}

sub word_split {
    my $str = shift;
    my $delimeter = "\n";
    $str = fix_parens($str);
    $str =~ s/([[(])/$delimeter$1/g;
    $str =~ s/([])])/$1$delimeter/g;
    my @tot = split /$delimeter/, $str;
    @tot = fix_nested(@tot);
    return @tot;
}
my $str = "Hey [there ](you|my [friendly ]friend) where's my [red|blue]berry?";
my @sentences = expand_words($str);
print "$_\n" for (@sentences);
print scalar @sentences . " sentences\n";
```

Will produce the output:

```
Hey you where's my berry?
Hey you where's my redberry?
Hey you where's my blueberry?
Hey my friend where's my berry?
Hey my friend where's my redberry?
Hey my friend where's my blueberry?
Hey my friendly friend where's my berry?
Hey my friendly friend where's my redberry?
Hey my friendly friend where's my blueberry?
Hey there you where's my berry?
Hey there you where's my redberry?
Hey there you where's my blueberry?
Hey there my friend where's my berry?
Hey there my friend where's my redberry?
Hey there my friend where's my blueberry?
Hey there my friendly friend where's my berry?
Hey there my friendly friend where's my redberry?
Hey there my friendly friend where's my blueberry?
18 sentences
```

Comment: I cannot rely on no spaces inside the braces, in fact I **want** nested expressions. I have solved the original problem. I cannot self-answer for 8 hours so I appended the solution to my question. I thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @YGomez Well, like I said, you can always find another way besides `split` on whitespace. This is a working solution for both `[]` and `()`, with `|` inside.

Comment: @YGomez Made a complete revision. It should work as expected now. If you can come up with a better answer, my hat's off to you.

Comment: @TLP: This works well for non-nested statements. If I give it: `my $str = "Hey [there ](you|my [friendly ]friend) where's my [red|blue]berry?";` Then it breaks. I'm afraid the nesting might be more verbose. This is quite compact though, albeit I don't understand it very well. Also, I don't like that the input needs to be formatted in an unnatural way. Overall though good solution, +1.

Comment: @YGomez Oho, curve balls.. well, here's something: `[there ]` is equal to `(there |)`, so `[]` can be excluded to make things a lot simpler. Also, `(you |my (friendly |)friend)` can be replaced with `(you |my friend |my friendly friend )` dynamically.

Comment: @TLP: Thank you for the considerable effort you've put into your answer. I have not gotten either your solution or the one I've been working on to work how it needs to work (which needs to be fairly robust). I am going to continue working on this tomorrow. If I get your answer to work I will let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: @YGomez You're welcome. It was a fun challenge. If you let me know with what input it fails, I'm sure I can fix it.

Comment: @TLP: I will let you know tomorrow. Although I might try to solve it myself. After all, I will have to maintain this code eventually...and honestly I don't understand it completely yet.

Comment: @TLP: I have edited the question. The original question I posted quickly evolved from "why is my code not working" to "how can I implement parenthesis and the or operator." I have accepted your answer because it is the closest thing posted to what I needed, and it actually works for the most part quite well. However, I could not shake the feeling that this was not the right way of doing things. So I have decided to take a more theoretically rigorous approach which I originally believed to be "overkill." Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[Data::Generate](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aGenerate). I found this while searching for *combination* which is the mathematical term of what you're doing with your sets of words there.

Comment: Very nice library, but I can't see how it would be useful for the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather simple solution, if you get past some of the ugly regexps, due to collisions between your syntax and the regexp syntax. It allows for both the [] and the () syntax, which in fact are very similar, [foo] is the same as (foo| ).

The basis is to replace each alternation by a marker #0, #1, #2... while storing them in an array. then replace the last marker, generating several phrases, then replace the next-to last marker in each of those phrases... until all markers have been replaced. Attentive readers of [Higher-order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) will no doubt find a more elegant way to do this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while( my $phrase=<DATA>)
  { my $original= $phrase;
    $phrase=~s{\[([^\]]*)\]}{($1| )}g;           # replace [c|d] by (c|d| )
    my $alts=[]; my $i=0;
    while( $phrase=~ s{\(([^)]*)\)}{#$i})        # replace (a|b) ... (c|d| )  by #0 ... #1
      { push @$alts, [ split /\|/, $1 ]; $i++;   # store [ ['a', 'b'], [ 'c', 'd', ' '] ]
      }

    my $expanded=[$phrase];                       # seed the expanded list with the phrase

    while( @$alts) { expand( $alts, $expanded); } # expand each alternation, until none left

    print "$original    - ", join( "    - ", @$expanded), "\n\n";

  }

exit;

# expand the last #i of the phrase in all the phrases in $expanded
sub expand
  { my( $alts, $expanded)=@_;
    my @these_alts= @{pop(@$alts)};   # the last alternations 
    my $i= @$alts;                    # the corresponding index in the phrases

    @$expanded= map { my $ph= $_;               
                     map { my $ph_e= $ph;       
                           $ph_e=~ s{#$i}{$_};  # replace the marker #i by one option
                           $ph_e=~ s{ +}{ };    # fix double spaces
                           $ph_e;
                         } @these_alts          # for all options
                   } @$expanded                 # for all phrases stored so far
  }


__DATA__
(His|Her) dog was [very|extremely
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention of Higher Order Perl. I had not heard about it but it sounds like a great thing to read after I finish Perl Best Practices.

Comment: @YGomez it's a good book, I am pretty sure after re-reading it I would rewrite the code in a cleaner way. Oh well...